# How to set and get an array of SimpleStringProperty

Tags: arrays, javafx, javabeans, getter-setter

I am trying to set and get values of some fields using javafx beans. The problem is I am able to do it with "StringProperty specialization" but not with "StringProperty degrees[]" which is an array of string property because set method in below code is not working:

```
   private StringProperty degrees[];
  //getter and setter for degrees array

   public final void setDegrees(String[] degrees) {

    **this.degreesProperty().set(degrees);**
} 
 public final StringProperty[] degreesProperty() {

    if (degrees == null) {
        SimpleStringProperty degree[]=new SimpleStringProperty[100];
        degree[0]=new SimpleStringProperty("");
        degree[1]=new SimpleStringProperty("");
        degrees =degree;
        return degrees;
    } else {

        return degrees;
    }
}
```

Whereas below code is working fine:

```
     private StringProperty specialization;
    
    //getter and setter for specialization
    public final void setSpecialization(String specialization) {
    this.specializationProperty().set(specialization);
}

public final StringProperty specializationProperty() {

    if (specialization == null) {

        specialization = new SimpleStringProperty("");
        return specialization;
    } else {

        return specialization;
    }
}

public final String getSpecialization() {

    if (specialization != null) {
        return specialization.get();
    } else {
        return "";
    }
}
```

Comment: Why don't you use an [`ObservableList`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/javafx/collections/ObservableList.html) or [`ObservableArray`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/javafx/collections/ObservableArray.html)?

Comment: requirement is to do with javafx beans only e.g. SimpleStringProperty

Comment: What is the specific requirement? Where does it come from?

Comment: does it means its not doable with beans?

Comment: What is not doable? You haven't explained what you are trying to do.

Comment: As the title suggest I am trying to get and set some string fields using javafx beans but not able to get and set values for an array of String.

Comment: So, I repeat, why don't you use an `ObservableList`? Or an `ObjectProperty<String[]>`, depending on what you actually want to do.

Comment: Solved: used this.degreesProperty().setAll(StringPropertyDegrees); instead of just set() method